# Multiple Edittext inside scrollview

Tags: android

Hi I have multiple editext inside scrollview vertically, when I  do scroll then unable to go to last edittext ,edittext in middle get focused always.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the attributes **android:focusable** and **android:focusableintouchmode.**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFirst"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableintouchmode="true">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSecond"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableintouchmode="true">
</EditText>
```

Comment: I set android:focusable="false" and android:focusableintouchmode="true" now edittext not getting focus when i touch edittext

Comment: @NehaShukla : In all your edit texts- put android:focusable ="true" and android:focusableintouchmode="true". And then put <requestFocus /> tag in the first edit text. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmailET"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus /> <!--add this line to the first EditText where you want to get focus-->
    </EditText>
```